# How to change layout for article in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla3.0

Is it possible in Joomla to override whole layout for article (not only article component layout)? I have two columns website (with modules in right column) but for some articles i need one column design.

Comment: Where's your specific detailed programming question with example code to show your working?

Comment: Why not give the articles a particular class attribute then use CSS to style/format the element.

Comment: how can i add class to article? or add it directly to articles HTML?

Comment: This question would probably be better received at http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Articles Associated with a Menu Item**

Edit the right column modules in Extensions -> Modules, and go to the Menu Assignment tab to disable modules on particular pages so that the sidebar collapses and the full width of the template will be used by the main content.

**Articles Not Associated with a Menu Item**

As far as I am aware, there is no provision for an article CSS class in the same way there is a page class for a menu item.

A crude way to implement this would be to install the free or paid version of [Regular Labs Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer) or similar so that you can include some code in the article to dynamically add some CSS like this or similar:

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$style = '.sidebar {'
          . 'display: none;'
          . '}'
          . '.main-content {'
          . 'width: 100%;'
          . '}';
$document->addStyleDeclaration($style);
?>
```

Even better, add the code to a custom HTML module (remember to set "Prepare Content" to "Yes" under the Options tab) with a custom module position such as `full-width` and then include the following code in the articles you wish to make full width:

```
{loadposition full-width}
```

Comment: but that means, each fullwidth article should be assigned to some menu. There is no other way for example like in [wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)?

Comment: Joomla is menu driven so there is no easy solution for this as far as I am aware. I have updated my answer with a crude work around.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, understanding Joomla logic after Wordpress is really hard